# jquery select asp element with cssclass

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am attempting to check the checkbox (when clicking the label) by using its cssClass identifier.  It works fine if I use the checkbox ID but for some reason I am unable to access the checkbox using the class identifier.

here is the javascript:

```
   $(function () {
        $('#label').click(function () {
            $('.checkBox').prop('checked', true);
        });
   });
```

here is the html:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="label" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" cssClass="checkBox" ClientIDMode="Static"  runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: try changing your classname

Comment: If you just place the checkbox inside the label it works without any JS ?

Comment: Tried changing class name, no go, and I have a gridview full of these checkboxes I was hoping to access and iterate through using their class which seemed to be the easiest solution I was finding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at rendered HTML for that page, you will see that checkbox is renderd as:

```
<span class="checkBox" ClientIDMode="Static"><input id="CheckBox1" type="checkbox" name="CheckBox1" /></span>
```

The class is assigned to outer span. You need to adjust your selector accordingly.

Comment: Bummer, thanks for the answer as to why I was unable to find my checkbox.

Comment: You still should be able to find it as a child of element found by class. Please mark as answered if solution was helpful

Comment: Got it with  `$('.checkBox').find('>:first-child').prop('checked', true);`